# RecyclerView Crash while fast scrolling and filtering at the same time

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

The filter itself works fine, the RecyclerView as well. It handles fast scrolling as intended until I scroll fast and change the filter. I get the following error message:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 63(offset:63).state:185 androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{f4c2e9b VFED.V... ........ 0,683-1440,2690 #7f09012c app:id/recylcerViewItems}, adapter:com.blazecode.scrapguide.ItemListAdapter@eae53a0, layout:androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager@b748b59, context:com.blazecode.scrapguide.MainActivity@1ba08b4
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6183)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.prefetchPositionWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:288)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.flushTaskWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:345)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.flushTasksWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:361)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.prefetch(GapWorker.java:368)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.run(GapWorker.java:399)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

I already tried `mRecyclerView.stopScroll();` right before `mAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);` with no success. I think this lowered the probability of it crashing, but its still occuring.

**ItemListAdapter.class:**

```
public class ItemListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemListAdapter.ItemViewHolder> implements Filterable {

private ArrayList<Item> mItemList;
private ArrayList<Item> mItemListFiltered;

private ItemsListAdapterListener mItemsListAdapterListener;


public ItemListAdapter(ArrayList<Item> itemArrayList, ItemsListAdapterListener itemsListAdapterListener) {

    mItemList = itemArrayList;
    mItemListFiltered = itemArrayList;
    this.mItemsListAdapterListener = itemsListAdapterListener;
}


public interface ItemsListAdapterListener {
    void onItemClick(Item item);
}



public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    public ImageView mImageView;
    public TextView mTextView;


    ItemsListAdapterListener mItemsListAdapterListener;

    public ItemViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, ItemsListAdapterListener itemsListAdapterListener) {
        super(itemView);


        mItemsListAdapterListener = itemsListAdapterListener;

        mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewItem);
        mTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewItem);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mItemsListAdapterListener.onItemClick(mItemListFiltered.get(getAdapterPosition()));
        //Log.i("test", "Adapter click");
    }

}


@NonNull
@Override
public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_item_layout, parent, false);
    ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder = new ItemViewHolder(view, mItemsListAdapterListener);
    return  itemViewHolder;

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Item item = mItemListFiltered.get(position);

    holder.mImageView.setImageResource(item.getImgURL());
    holder.mTextView.setText(item.getItemName());


}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            String charString = charSequence.toString();
            if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                mItemListFiltered = mItemList;
            } else {
                ArrayList<Item> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Item row: mItemList) {

                    // name match condition. this might differ depending on your requirement
                    // here we are looking for name or phone number match
                    if (row.getItemName().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase()) || row.getItemCategory().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase())) {

                        filteredList.add(row);

                    }
                }

                mItemListFiltered = (ArrayList<Item>) filteredList;
            }

            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = mItemListFiltered;
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            mItemListFiltered = (ArrayList<Item>) filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mItemListFiltered.size();
}
}
```

**ItemFragment.class part which is setting the filter:**

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    mAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    if(mAdapter.getItemCount() == 0){
        mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        constraintLayoutMissingItem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        constraintLayoutMissingItem.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Why is it throwing this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Cause of problem:**
As you were doing fast scrolling, the ultimate index to reach when the `RecylerView` comes to `IDLE` would already be calculated. Now, when it tries to access the item at that index, it will not find it. The reason is you had already reset the `mFilteredListItem` in your `mAdapter` with newer `mFilteredListItem`(which is not likely to have that many items).
**Solution No: 1**
You can use the flag concept to check whether or not you can show the filtered results immediately to avoid the crash. For that create a boolean variable like this:

```
 boolean shouldShowFilteredResults = true;
```

Then, add `OnScrollListener()` in your `RecyclerView` to find out how fast is it scrolling in order to enable or disable our flag variable accordingly as:

```
rcView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                // get rid of every earlier code written here
                // when dx=dy=0, then then method is not called
                // that's why earlier code was not working
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    if (!shouldshowFilteredResults) 
                        shouldshowFilteredResults = true;
                } else {
                    if (shouldshowFilteredResults) 
                        shouldshowFilteredResults = false;
                }
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }
        });
```

**Side Note:** You can also use `onScrollStateChanged` to check for changes in `RecyclerView` state such as `SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING`, `SCROLL_STATE_IDLE` and `SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING` to set the value of our flag variable appropriately.

Then, inside `onTextChanged()` method, check `shouldShowFilteredResults` variable to find out whether to show results immediately or not.

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if(shouldShowFilteredResults)
        mAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);

}
```

**Solution No: 2**
You can use non-smooth version of `scrollToPosition(0)` to scroll to the first position instantaneously rather than calling `stopScrolling()`.Then, make a delayed call to `mAdapter.getFilter().filter(s)` method using `Handler` object.
**Suggestions:**(this is not related to answer)

- I found two variables `mItemList` and `mItemFilteredList` in `ItemListAdapter` to have same values initially and then the 2nd one is used the whole time. If you don't need one, you can get rid of it.
- Inside the `getFilter()` method, you wrote
  `filterResults.values = mItemListFiltered;`
  then, later inside `publishResults()`, you wrote
  `mItemListFiltered = (ArrayList<Item>) filterResults.values;`
  which I think is redundant.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time involved. I tried both suggested solutions and unfortunately both won't work out for me. The first method results in no filtering at all, even when the list isn't scrolling. The second solution crashes with the exact same logcat error.

Comment: I found that when dy==0, the method is not called. So, you need to use `onScrollStateChanged` method. In 2nd solution, try to use `Handler` object to delay the call to `filter()` method to see if it will work. See my edited answer. It should work.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works fine! Just out of curiosity, is this actually the best practice way?

Comment: Did both work for you ? I guess, people will rarely fast scroll and try to filter at the same time unless they want to break your app. I think, the best practice would be to dispatch the call to the `filter(currentStr)` method after the `recyclerview` stops scrolling. But, I think it is kind of difficult to implement. Anyway a better thing to do regarding my first solution would be to notify the user that they can't filter during scrolling. I believe user shouldn't be deprived of that information.

Comment: To be fair I just tried the first solution, because it isnt as much prone to errors as the second one in my opinion. I think I will implement a Toast as a reminder not to fastscroll and filter at the same time. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had also observed that the filtering recyclerview while it is still under scroll state (ie., not yet come to halt after scroll) caused IndexOutOfBoundException triggered.
The solution, I found out, is putting the logic of filtering and populating a new list in publishResults method, not in performFiltering method. In performFiltering, just return new Filter.FilterResults(); Then, you won't face problem mentioned in the question.
Also, there is no need of tracking scroll state and checking it before attempting filter as mentioned in the accepted answer.